# Up and down arrow inserting unwanted character in tkinter.Entry widget

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter

The following code produces an app with a single `Entry` widget. When run on MacOS using Python 3.7.3 from Homebrew, pressing the up or down arrow while inside the entry box causes a character 0xF701 to be inserted:

[image: Down key introduces character]

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
app = tk.Frame(master=root)
app.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(app)
entry.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

This doesn't happen with Anaconda Python and I haven't been able to find anyone else having this issue.

By binding `print` to the up and down events I've been able to see that the character associated with these events is indeed `0xF700` and `0xF701`.

```
entry.bind('<Down>', print)
entry.bind('<Up>', print)
```

Output after pressing up and down:

```
<KeyPress event state=Mod3|Mod4 keysym=Up keycode=8320768 char='\uf700' delta=8320768 x=-5 y=-50>
<KeyPress event state=Mod3|Mod4 keysym=Down keycode=8255233 char='\uf701' delta=8255233 x=-5 y=-50>
```

With the Anaconda Python version the output is slightly different:

```
<KeyPress event state=Mod3|Mod4 keysym=Up keycode=8320768 char='\uf700' x=-5 y=-50>
<KeyPress event state=Mod3|Mod4 keysym=Down keycode=8255233 char='\uf701' x=-5 y=-50>
```

Does anyone know of a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: I ran this on my own mac and I'm getting the same problem, this might just be a problem with tkinter on the Mac OS. I'll try think of a solution.

Comment: @MatthewG: It has to do with tkinter packages bundled with python on anaconda and python installed on Homebrew. They are definitely not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Can validating the Entry help?  The code below validates that the resulting string in Entry only contains characters in `valid_chars`.  A more complex validation rule could be written if required.

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

valid_chars = re.compile(r'^[0-9A-Za-z ]*$') # Accept Alphanumeric and Space

class ValidateEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, regex):
        self.valid = regex
        validate_cmd = (parent.register(self.validate),'%P') # %P pass the new string to validate
        super().__init__( parent, validate = 'key', validatecommand = validate_cmd)
        #  validate = 'key' runs the validation at each keystroke.

    def validate(self, new_str):
        if self.valid.match(new_str): return True
        return False

def do_key(ev):
    print(ev.widget, ev, entry.get())

root= tk.Tk()
root.title("Validation")
fram = tk.Frame(root)
fram.grid()

entry = ValidateEntry(fram, valid_chars)
entry.grid()
entry.bind('<Down>', do_key)
entry.bind('<Up>', do_key)

root.mainloop()
```

This may be overkill but should work across all the platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The release why you are getting those unknown characters in an `Entry` widget is because for some reason char codes of *"Up"* (\uf700) and *"Down"* (\uf701) arrows prints `` when run from homebrew python but not with anaconda python not sure why is that.

You can try and see yourself by running this code with either of them.

```
root = Tk()
E = Entry(root)
E.bind('<Key>', lambda e: print(e.char))
E.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

The solution I come up with is to overwrite the main `<Key>` bind of `Entry` widget to ignore  *"Up"* and *"Down"* arrows.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Entry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        super(Entry, self).__init__(master=master, cnf=cnf, **kw)
        self.bind_class('Entry', '<Key>', self.add_char)

    def add_char(self, evt):
        if evt.char != '\uf701' and evt.char != '\uf700':
            self.insert('insert', evt.char)
            self.xview_moveto(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    E = Entry(root)
    E.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works as long as you are adding characters at the end. If your trying to change "Fred" to "Freed" you end up with "Frede".

Comment: @TlsChris: thanks for pointing it out I changed the index to "insert".

Comment: That's lighter than my answer.  I've never tried to use insert in an Entry.  I like the way the cnf and keywords are carried through to the super too.

Comment: @TlsChris: You can also carry `cnf` and `kw` to the `super()` as well or just use `**kw` and update `validate` and `validate_cmd` like so `kw['validate'] = 'key'`...